# How to make my two columns responsive?

Tags: html, css, grid-layout, css-grid

I am displaying two columns in the center of my grid with contents and I need to make these two columns above each other in mobile view how I can do that?

```css
.two-pics {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 50px;
  grid-template-columns: 400px 400px;
  object-fit: cover;
  color: #444;
  margin-top: 100px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  background-color: white;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.a {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1 / 12;
}

.b {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 12;
}
```

```html
<div class="two-pics">
  <div class="box a">
    <img src="assets/images/pic1.jpg">
    <br>
    <p>title</p>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li>dfgdfghdfhdfh</li>
      <li>dfgdfghdfhdfh</li>
      <li>dfgdfghdfhdfh</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="box b">
    <img src="assets/images/pic2.jpg">
    <br>
    <p>ldkjh ldkjfh ldk hjf</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try [using media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)?

Comment: @RaulSauco I forgot about media queries thanks alot. just curious can grid do that without media queries ?

Comment: setting the max-width of your columns would make them display side by side on wider screens and one below the other on smaller screens but you would need uniform margins/paddings if you didn't want them to look different when displayed vertically. It seems like media queries would be the best way to approach this but I guess that you could go without

Comment: I highly recommend using `flexbox` for one-dimensional lists. True, we don't yet have `flex-gap`, but [that's coming soon](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1696)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `auto-fit` property you can create as many `400px` grid tracks as will fit in the container.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rdXXGj)

```css
body {
  background: grey;
}

.two-pics {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 50px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 400px);
  color: #444;
  margin-top: 100px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  background-color: white;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 150%;
}
```

```html
<div class="two-pics">
  <div class="box a">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/400">
    <br>
    <p>title</p>
    <ul>
      <li>dfdfd</li>
      <li>dfgdfghdfhdfh</li>
      <li>dfgdfghdfhdfh</li>
      <li>dfgdfghdfhdfh</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="box b">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/400">
    <br>
    <p>ldkjh ldkjfh ldk hjf</p>
  </div>
</div>
```